# Python zip pattern in R

Tags: python, r

How to do in R something like this, to a class container:

```
class Env(object):
      pass
env = Env()
```

I want to add instances attributes using a (python like) zip pattern:

```
medias_name = ("myprint", "ooh", "tv", "digital")
medias_img = ("Print.png", "Ooh.png", "Tv.png", "Digital.png")

for name, value in zip(medias_name, medias_img):
      setattr(env, name, value)

env.digital, env.myprint, env.ooh, env.tv
>>> ('Digital.png', 'Print.png', 'Ooh.png', 'Tv.png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can emulate the python zip with a data.frame like this::

```
medias_name <- c("print", "ooh", "tv", "digital")
medias_img <- c("Print.png", "Ooh.png", "Tv.png", "Digital.png")

myenv <- new.env()
zip_df <- data.frame(name=medias_name, img=medias_img, stringsAsFactors=F)
for (i in 1:nrow(zip_df)){
  myenv[[zip_df[i, 'name']]] <- zip_df[i, 'img']
}
```

So we get::

```
> zip_df
name         img
1   print   Print.png
2     ooh     Ooh.png
3      tv      Tv.png
4 digital Digital.png

> ls(myenv)
[1] "digital" "ooh"     "print"   "tv"     

> myenv$tv
[1] "Tv.png"
>
```

Another solution is to emulate zip with a list to pack items::

```
medias_name <- c("print", "ooh", "tv", "digital")
medias_img <- c("Print.png", "Ooh.png", "Tv.png", "Digital.png")

myenv <- new.env()
ziplist <- list(medias_name, medias_img)
for (i in 1:length(ziplist[[1]])){
    name <- ziplist[[1]][i]
    img <- ziplist[[2]][i]
    myenv[[name]] <- img
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
medias_name <- ("myprint", "ooh", "tv", "digital") 
medias_img <- ("Print.png", "Ooh.png", "Tv.png", "Digital.png")
myenv <- new.env()
mapply(function(x, y) menv[[x]] <- y, medias_name, medias_img)
```